# Installing Kali Linux

Tags: package-management, password, kali-linux

This is my 4th attempt at installing Kali Linux mini on Dell Inspiron 1545 Laptop.

When I get to dialog that says "Select components to install" there is no way to select additional components

- it won't allow me to enter Fn+8 for asterisk
- if I press Enter it jumps to the next step

And when it finally installs it doesn't have the package I need, ie password tools ....

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is check if the image you used to burn the cd/made a bootable drive with is OK and if it was downloaded from the official Kali Linux website (http://kali.org).

Kali has a "Verifying Your Downloaded Kali Image" section on their website, see: http://docs.kali.org/introduction/download-official-kali-linux-images#manual

Comment: yes I downloaded from correct site, will verify image

Answer (score 1):

OK I re-installed again.

I was able to download password tools

`sudo apt-get install kali-linux-pwtools`